# Concurrent Timeout Exception using SQLCipher in android

Tags: android, exception, timeout, sqlcipher-android

I am using SqlCipher in my android application to encrypt the database. 
My app works in both online and offline and has many DB transactions.

I am using SQLCipher 3.5.7 version.

I rarely get the below exception and it occur mostly in Samsung devices. 
I was unable to reproduce the exception. Kindly help.

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.finalize() timed out after 60 seconds at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method) at 
java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137) at 
sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:868) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:900) at 
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1223) at 

java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:225) at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:286) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:553) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.releaseSqlStatement(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:106) at 
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.finalize(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:152) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250) at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237) at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```